# How to choose a timestamp data type value from a LOV in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle-apex, lov

See imagehttps://i.stack.imgur.com/BSlpn.jpg

What is a simple way to insert timestamp values in my setup?

The LOV right now exists of static content, I just filled in the '10:00' manually.

Still a noob so I'm sorry if this is very obvious.

Comment: Do you have a Format Mask defined on the field that matches the format of the return value of your LOV?

Comment: Do you mean like setting a date format? No I do not. I also do not know where in the application I should define this Format Mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the APEX page designer, after selecting your **Tijd** field, you need to set the format mask that matches the format of the **Return Value** of your LOV. I created a quick [demo application](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-testing/timestamp-test) that shows the difference between using a format mask and not using a format mask.

[image]

This is what my LOV definition looks like:

[image]

Comment: I see. And did you set the time format in the LOV as a Dynamic Action or am I not even close? 

Thank you for helping btw

Comment: @JtothyY - Just added a screenshot of my LOV definition

Comment: Ah I think I get it, I'm going to try this. Thanks!